# ¿Crear objetos dinamicamente en tiempo de ejecución?

Tags: c++, punteros, array

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <windows.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <conio.h>
#define UP 72
#define RIGHT 77
#define LEFT 75
#define DOWN 80

using namespace std;

int rand_num(int first, int to){
    return (first+rand() % (to +1 - first));
}

void gotoxy(int _x, int _y){
    COORD dwpos;
    dwpos.X = _x; dwpos.Y = _y;

    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),dwpos);
}

struct object{
    int x,y;
    char icon;
    string type;

    object(){}
    object(int _x, int _y, char _icon, string _type):x(_x),y(_y),icon(_icon),type(_type){}

    void print(){
        gotoxy(x,y);
        cout << icon;
    }

    void clean(){
        gotoxy(x,y);
        cout << ' ';
    }
};

int main(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    int q = 0;
    char ctrl;
    object **star = new object*;
    object *p = NULL;
    star[q++] = new object(0,0,'P',"player");
    star[0]->print();
    while(1){
        if(kbhit()){
            ctrl = getch();
            for(int i = 0; i < q; i++){
                star[i]->clean();
            }
            if(ctrl == LEFT){
                for(int i = 0; i < q; i++){
                    if(star[i]->type == "player"){
                        star[i]->x--;
                    }
                }
            }else if(ctrl == RIGHT){
                for(int i = 0; i < q; i++){
                    if(star[i]->type == "player"){
                        star[i]->x++;
                    }
                }
            }else if(ctrl == DOWN){
                for(int i = 0; i < q; i++){
                    if(star[i]->type == "player"){
                        p = &*star[i];
                        p->y++;
                    }
                }
            }else if(ctrl == UP){
                for(int i = 0; i < q; i++){
                    if(star[i]->type == "player"){
                        star[i]->y--;
                    }
                }
            }else if (ctrl == 'a'){
                star[q++] = new object(rand_num(0,30),rand_num(0,30),'O',"another");
            }else if(ctrl == 'b'){
                if(q>1){
                    delete star[--q];
                }
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < q; i++){
                star[i]->print();
            }
        }
    }
return 0;}
```

Este es mi programa, y queria saber si hay una forma de crear objetos en tiempo de ejecución, me explico?

No se como usar los punteros de esa forma y no se si los estoy usando como deberia, quizas deberia usar listas enlazadas.

El fin de esto es, para poder programar videojuegos, y los objetos se creen o se carguen mientras el juego esta en ejecución.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
object **star = new object*;
```

Estás intentando crear una lista de punteros... la línea anterior es incorrecta porque la reserva únicamente te va a permitir guardar un puntero. Sería más correcto hacer:

```
object** star = new object*[20]; // Para guardar 20 elementos
```

O esto:

```
object* star[20]; // y te ahorras un new
```

Aunque siempre será preferible hacer uso de la STL (Standard Template Library):

```
std::vector<object*> star; // Contenedor para todos los punteros que necesites
```

Ahora, para añadir elementos a la colección puedes hacer:

```
star.push_back(new object(0,0,'P',"player"));
```

Usando `std::vector`, podrás acceder a los elementos sin tocar esa parte del código (usando el operador []), sin embargo, por coherencia, sería recomendable usar `size_t` en vez de `int` (`size_t` es un alias de tipo `unsigned`)

```
            for(size_t i = 0; i < star.size(); i++){
                if(star[i]->type == "player"){
                    star[i]->x--;
                }
            }
```

Aunque también puedes usar iteradores:

```
// Codigo tradicional
std::vector<object*>::iterator it;
for( it = star.begin(); it != star.end(); ++it )
  if( (*it)->type == "player"){
    (*it)->x--;
  }
}

// C++11 v1
for( auto it = star.begin(); it != star.end(); ++it )
  if( (*it)->type == "player"){
    (*it)->x--;
  }
}

// C++11 v2
for( auto ptr : star)
  if( ptr->type == "player"){
    ptr->x--;
  }
}
```

Por supuesto nunca hay que olvidar liberar la memoria al final

```
for( auto ptr : star )
  delete ptr;
```

Comment: Me gustaria saber que hace el `for( auto ptr: star)`, ya que nunca he usado algo asi en mi vida XD

Comment: Y creo que no necesito crear un vector de puntero si puedo  usar el vector en si,
`std::vector<object> star;`

Comment: @JoséDanielFloresMorales ese for aparece en c++11 y por dentro llama a begin y end. En cada iteración extrae el dato del iterador y con ello ejecuta el código que le pongas al bucle. En cuanto al segundo comentario, si almacenas objetos en vez de punteros no podrás usar polimorfismo y te arriesgas a hacer un sin fín de copias de los objetos a nada que te despistes... pero es una solucion y no te la he presentado porque con tu ejemplo no se podia deducir si era viable eliminar los punteros